# why jquery .height() get a different result on chrome?

Tags: jquery

This is how chrome show the width and height of the div :

[image]

which is correct, in fact the height is 1466. But, if I do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('#container-altezza-fisso').height());
});
```

it prints 1418. It doesnt have any padding/margin. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What other style rules are applied to that element? Does it have any particular children which dimensions (height) can change after their contents will be loaded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because on DOMReady some images are not loaded completely. You should call the height on window load.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log($('#container-altezza-fisso').height());
})
```

You can also use `outerHeight`:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

```
console.log($('#container-altezza-fisso').outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `outerHeight()` to get the height with paddings.
Use `outerHeight(true)` to get the height with paddings + margins.

[Here's a link to the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Comment: As I said, I've no paddings/margin! It works putting the code on $(window).load... :O

Answer (score 2):

`.height()` will get you the element's height, `.outerHeight()` will return the height including padding, margin and borders.