# jQuery : $('div.myclass').height() is not accurate

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why jquery .height() get a different result on chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709506/why-jquery-height-get-a-different-result-on-chrome)

I have a `<div>` with CSS class `myclass`. The CSS class is as follow:

```
.myclass {
    position: absolute;
    width: 192px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);    
    display: block;
}
```

It does not specify height. Contents are loaded dynamically by PHP. In jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { });`, I debug the height of the div by:

```
console.log($('div.myclass').height()); // the result = 330
```

HTML :

```
<div class="myclass">
<img src="image.png" />
<p>Text here text here</p>
</div>
```

However, if I use the `Inspect Element` feature in Google Chrome, it shows **531px**. Why there is a difference? How can I get the `531px` value?

**UPDATE**: `$(this).outerHeight(); // 345px, as there is 15px margin`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try putting your code within window load handler, also as your element has `15px` padding property, you should use `outerHeight` method:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log($('div.myclass').outerHeight()); 
});
```

Note that `outerHeight` accepts a boolean value, false means exclude the margin and true means add the margin, also note that outerHeight returns the height of the first matched element with that class name.

Comment: already in `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor window on load is not document  on ready.

Comment: this works! the `$(this).outerHeight();` value is accurate when `$(window).load`. But why `$(document).ready` doesn't work?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The ready event fires when DOM is ready, load event fires when all the images and iframes are loaded completely.

Comment: still working not exactly. I don't know why?

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log($('div.myclass').outerHeight());
```

The outherHeight will also take into account padding and margin.

EDIT: if you don't need the margin, use `innerHeight()` instead.

Comment: I tried. the `outerHeight()` added the margin, but still, around 200px is missing. Is it related to the image in the DIV does not have a height?

Comment: The element has only 15px padding, it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: It's probably calculating the height before the image is loaded. If it's always a fixed size, you could try setting the height in the `<img>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/swVLf/ (run once with the height included in the `img` tag, and then remove it to see what happens... ;))

Comment: Calculate the outerHeight() of the div using the console of chrome. Does it return 531px as well? Otherwise, you can try setting a delay, but I think it should be loaded on jquery ready event.

Comment: still working not exactly. I don't know why?

Answer (score 3):

It is accurate actually.

- [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function tells you the height of the block element, without padding and margin
- [innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) function tells you the height of the block element, with padding but without margin
- [outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) function tells you the height of the block element with padding and margin